# Where was this picture taken? Somewhere in the western USA? Zion or Capitol Reef national park?

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth, photography, national-parks, locate-this

Need help identifying a location. I think it's most likely somewhere in the western USA. Maybe Zion or Capitol Reef national park based on the orange rock and river?[image]

Comment: "Orange rock" describes most of southern Utah and northern Arizona.

Comment: Is that a monolith? :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would guess somewhere in/near Zion NP. The river + cliffs looks similar to the Virgin River. On the left side of the image through the trees the sandstone appears more white which is a common site in Zion.

Also, I think I spy some ponderosa pine trees which are commonly found on the high plateau that Zion canyon is carved out of. These trees pull me away from guesses like Capital Reef or the Escalante river.